# Arrow keys switching control in TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, c++builder, twebbrowser

I have a problem with `TWebBrowser` (MSHTML/IE) handling of arrow-keys.

Basically, if I host `TWebBrowser` and load a HTML file, it displays it incorrectly and arrow keys work. If I add a registry key `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` or use `X-UA-Compatible` meta header it renders the HTML properly but arrow keys stop working (they do work, but they want to "tab" to other control so content scrolling no longer works). It looks as if the keys drop to the main form before (or after) being processed by the `TWebBrowser`.

I found a solution by handling keydown event and then using something like:

`WebBrowser1->Document->parentWindow->scrollBy(0, 100);`

This solution works, but I found something better which I'm trying to translate into Delphi/C++ Builder:

This C# code I found does the following:

```c#
private void webBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down || e.KeyCode == Keys.Up || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            e.IsInputKey = true;
            return;
        }
    }
```

I can do something similar with `KeyPreview` set to `true` on the form and then handling the VK_LEFT / VK_RIGHT / VK_DOWN / VK_UP keys in the KeyDown event of the form, or use other message handling or ApplicationEvents, to set the Key to 0 (or Handled to `true`, same effect) for example:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::ApplicationEventsMessage(tagMSG &Msg, bool &Handled)
{
if (Msg.message == WM_KEYDOWN && ActiveControl &&
   ActiveControl->InheritsFrom(__classid(TWebBrowser))
   )
    {
    if (Msg.wParam == VK_LEFT)  {Handled = true; return;}
    if (Msg.wParam == VK_RIGHT) {Handled = true; return;}
    if (Msg.wParam == VK_UP)    {Handled = true; return;}
    if (Msg.wParam == VK_DOWN)  {Handled = true; return;}
    }
}
```

Problem is, it is not the same thing. `IsInputKey`, if set to `true`, appears to process the keys only for the `TWebBrowser` control in the above C# code, but there is no such equivalent that I've found in Delphi/C++ Builder.

Any idea how I can drop key processing for the Delphi/C++Builder main form which hosts the `TWebBrowser` and only let the `TWebBrowser` do the processing of the key event only for the arrow keys above?

A test HTML to load into WebBrowser control (if it is not scrollable for testing with arrow keys, simply increase the size of the font in the `<div>` tag:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- This meta tag ensures that TWebBrowser runs in IE-11 mode -->
    <!-- Which causes issues with scrolling with arrow keys -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="font-size:36px;">
      01<br>
      02<br>
      03<br>
      04<br>
      05<br>
      06<br>
      07<br>
      08<br>
      09<br>
      10<br>
      11<br>
      12<br>
      13<br>
      14<br>
      15<br>
      16<br>
      17<br>
      18<br>
      19<br>
      20<br>
      21<br>
      22<br>
      23<br>
      24<br>
      25<br>
      26<br>
      27<br>
      28<br>
      29<br>
      30<br>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code to reproduce - Create a form with a `TWebBrowser` and a `TButton` and add this into `TButton` code: (clicking into control - mouse wheel works, page up/down works, arrows up/down want to "tab" into the button (or other control):

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
WebBrowser1->Navigate("about:<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\"></head><body><div style=\"font-size:36px;\">01<br>02<br>03<br>04<br>05<br>06<br>07<br>08<br>09<br>10<br>11<br>12<br>13<br>14<br>15<br>16<br>17<br>18<br>19<br>20<br>21<br>22<br>23<br>24<br>25<br>26<br>27<br>28<br>29<br>30<br></div></body></html>");
}
```

Comment: search for the source code of the TEmbeddedWB component, they solved this issue.

Comment: @whosrdaddy `TEmbeddedWB` was made way long before IE11 and besides, I have already tested with it and it produces the same problem with arrow keys.

Comment: Do you have a sample html file that I can test with?

Comment: @whosrdaddy Sure, I've updated the question. The relevant part is the `X-UA-Compatible` tag which makes the control behave in IE-11 mode and thus changes the functionality of the arrow keys unlike in the IE7 (default) mode when the `X-UA-Compatible` meta-tag is not present.

Comment: Please check this [code](https://pastebin.com/pvdYdXEt), it is Delphi, not c++ builder.This solved this issue for me (IOleInPlaceActiveObject is the key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @whosrdaddy - The following solution has worked (taken from [here](https://pastebin.com/pvdYdXEt)). The key was `IsDialogMessage` function.

```
// FIX voor webbrowser keys, install application wide message handler
constructor TBrowserHelper.Create(ADebug : TDebuggerSlot);
begin
 Debug := ADebug;
 if Assigned(Debug) then
  Debug.OutputL(Self, 'Create', '', LVL_SPARSE);
 OldMessageHandler := Application.OnMessage;
 Application.OnMessage :=  MsgHandler;
end;
 
destructor TBrowserHelper.Destroy;
begin
 if Assigned(Debug) then
  Debug.OutputL(Self, 'Destroy', '', LVL_SPARSE);
 Application.OnMessage := OldMessageHandler;
 inherited;
end;
 
procedure TBrowserHelper.MsgHandler(var Msg: TMsg; var Handled: Boolean);
 
const StdKeys = [VK_BACK, VK_UP, VK_DOWN, VK_LEFT, VK_RIGHT];
 
var IOIPAO: IOleInPlaceActiveObject;
    Browser : TEmbeddedWb;
 
begin
 try
  Browser := nil;
  if Assigned(Screen.ActiveForm) then
   begin
    if Screen.ActiveForm is TFrm_Browser then
     Browser := TFrm_Browser(Screen.ActiveForm).Browser;
    if Assigned(Browser) then
     begin
      Handled := IsDialogMessage(Browser.Handle, Msg);
      if Handled then//and (not Browser.Busy) then
       begin
//       if Assigned(Debug) then
//        Debug.OutputL(Self, 'MsgHandler', Format('Message: %x, wParam: %x, lParam: %x', [Msg.message, Msg.wParam, Msg.lParam]), LVL_FULL);
        if ((Msg.message = WM_KEYDOWN) or (Msg.message = WM_KEYUP)) and (Msg.wParam in StdKeys) then
         begin
          //nothing  -  do not pass on Backspace, Left, Right, Up, Down arrows
         end
        else
         begin
          IOIPAO := (Browser.Application as IOleInPlaceActiveObject);
          if Assigned(IOIPAO)then
           IOIPAO.TranslateAccelerator(Msg)
         end;
       end;
     end;
   end;
 except
  //Handled := False;  // leave it for other handlers
 end;
end;
 
initialization
begin
 iCaptSize := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION);
 iBorderSize := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXBORDER);
 iBorderThick := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSIZEFRAME);
 BrowserHelper := TBrowserHelper.Create(nil);
end;
 
finalization
begin
 if Assigned(BrowserHelper) then
  FreeAndNil(BrowserHelper);
end;
```